# How to export a XAML Silverlight Page into Pdf document?

Tags: xaml, pdf, silverlight-4.0, report

I am having a quite rich XAML page (silverlight), which serves as a kind of report on the screen.
I would like to export it to a document (preferrably PDF).

Any tools which are able to export the entire XAML page (or framework element) to a document with good quality?

Recently I have tried the ComponentOne's Pdf export which is supposed to do what I want, but I am dissatisfied with the quality.

Thanks a lot.